# Is it possible to use alsamixer eq with shairport-sync hifiberry amp2?

Tags: shairplay, hifiberry

I had shairport-sync functioning with a hifiberry amp2 butwhic the room it was intended for causes the setup to need some eq in a bad way.  I followed instructions I found at [GitHub](https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync/issues/233), but now I get no audio at all, and because I have no idea what I'm doing, I don't even know how to go back to how I started.

I think I can undo everything, but this command:

```
sudo cp -r /etc/skel /home/shairport-sync && sudo chown shairport-sync:shairport-sync /home/shairport-sync
```

This appears to have made a directory "shairport-sync" to the home directory, but other than that I am lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work and thought I should answer my own question incase the google leads a similarly confused person here.

After making the proper asound.conf file, the EQ has to be adjusted as if you are logged in as shairport-sync.

```
sudo -u shairport-sync alsamixer -D equal
```

I put up an [instructable](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Whole-Home-Synchronous-Audio-With-Pho/) with details.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.